# Exception with sqlite database "no such table"

Tags: database, vb.net, sqlite

First of all I´m developing a database with autosuggest box. I´ve created a database with DB Browser and imported data. I was reading documentation in C# how connect database and retrieve data. The issue is show up an exception error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyuoP.png)

I´ve connected the database in properties with content option. I paste the code:

```
Public NotInheritable Class METARTAF
Inherits Page


Dim dbpath As String = Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "airportsdb.sqlite3")
Dim conn As SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection = New SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(New WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), dbpath)
Dim airportinfo As List(Of String) = Nothing
Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

End Sub

Private Sub AutoSuggestBox_TextChanged(sender As AutoSuggestBox, args As AutoSuggestBoxTextChangedEventArgs)

    Dim datairport As New List(Of String)
    Dim retrieve = conn.Table(Of flugzeuginfo)().ToList

    If args.Reason = AutoSuggestionBoxTextChangeReason.UserInput Then
        If sender.Text.Length > 1 Then
            For Each item In retrieve
                datairport.Add(item.IATA)
                datairport.Add(item.ICAO)
                datairport.Add(item.Location)
                datairport.Add(item.Airport)
                datairport.Add(item.Country)
            Next

            airportinfo = datairport.Where(Function(x) x.StartsWith(sender.Text)).ToList()
            sender.ItemsSource = airportinfo
        End If
    Else
        sender.ItemsSource = "No results..."
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub AutoSuggestBox_SuggestionChosen(sender As AutoSuggestBox, args As AutoSuggestBoxSuggestionChosenEventArgs)
    Dim selectedItem = args.SelectedItem.ToString()
    sender.Text = selectedItem
End Sub

Private Sub AutoSuggestBox_QuerySubmitted(sender As AutoSuggestBox, args As AutoSuggestBoxQuerySubmittedEventArgs)
    If args.ChosenSuggestion Is Nothing Then
        stationidtxt.Text = args.ChosenSuggestion.ToString
    End If
End Sub
```

Anyone could help about this?

Comment: The error message seems fairly unambiguous to me. The database you're connecting to does not contain the table you're trying to query.

Answer (score 1):

Before you query or insert into a table, you should `CREATE` it.  This tells SQLite what columns you have and suggests datatypes (on other rdbms's you get actual data type enforcement but SQLite does not do that).  If this is your problem, you will want to spend some time with the SQLite documentation on data types and the ability to hook them into your application.

On the other hand, as you seem to be trying to retrieve data, this suggess one of two things is wrong.  Either you care connecting to the wrong db (in which case SQLite will usually helpfully create an empty db for you!) or else you are specifying the wrong table.

Comment: Hello Chris! The database and table is created. The table is flugzeuginfo but the localfolder where is? I imported the database from project. Is it enough to get data?

Comment: With SQLite, usually your connection string specifies a file location.

Comment: You are probably looking in the wrong place and so accidently creating a new, empty db.